# Plot intersection point of two curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am plotting the following filled area

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\begin{axis}[hide axis, clip bounding box=default tikz]
    \plot[name path=A, very thick,samples=201,domain=-1:1, color=blue] {sqrt(x*(x^2-x-1)+1};
    \plot[name path=B, very thick,samples=201,domain=-1:1, color=blue] {-sqrt(x*(x^2-x-1)+1};
    \addplot[fill=blue,opacity=.3] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-1:1}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces this output

[image]

As you can see the cusp at the right side is missing (when printed on paper, the gap is actually quite big). When slightly increasing the domain beyond 1, the cusp looks still a bit weird. My best solution so far is by adding a node at (1,0), which looks ok-ish but is not optimal. Are there better ways to deal with such a situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to draw it in one curve to have a `line join=miter`(default) that looks good. Then you might as well close the curve, so you can fill it. So you do not need `fillbetween`. You are also not really using `pgfplots` for anything. (also not using `xcolor`)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[blue, very thick, fill opacity=.3, samples=201]  plot[domain=-1:0.99] ( \x , {sqrt(\x*(\x*\x-\x-1)+1} )  --  plot[domain=1:-1] ( \x , {-sqrt(\x*(\x*\x-\x-1)+1} ) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled blue blob]

As you can see, your version in PGFplots is elongated, because you are missing the `axis equal` option in PGFplots. If you prefer the elongated version, then you can add e.g. `xscale=1.4` to the above code.

Answer (score 6):

An easy fix is to add `line cap=round`:

[image]

or `line cap=rect`:

[image]

to the `\plot` commands:

```
\plot[line cap=rect, name path=A, very thick,samples=201,domain=-1:1, color=blue] {sqrt(x*(x^2-x-1)+1};
\plot[line cap=rect, name path=B, very thick,samples=201,domain=-1:1, color=blue] {-sqrt(x*(x^2-x-1)+1};
```